# Can I cascade an HP D2600 from an MSA60

Tags: hp

We have an MSA60 running from a P800 controller in an ML350 server.

The MSA60 is full so we'd like to expand by cascading another disk enclosure and I notice there is now the D2600 (6G equivalent of the MSA60).

Does anyone have any experience cascading a D2600 off an MSA60?

I appreciate that HP's quickspecs don't list this as a supported configuration and we would only get 3G speeds, but I figured it would better if we could buy into current generation technology rather than hunt down an outdated MSA60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not only can you not daisy chain those two enclosures like that but the D2600 won't work with a P800 either sorry. If you had a P812 you could have the MSA60 off one port and the D2600 off the other but not daisy-chained sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I beg to disagree on the d2600 will not work on p800 part. We have two d2600 chained on a P800 as delivered by an HP partner and have not seen a problem. As for mix and match, we are trying to get an answer from HP regarding that.

Comment: They may work for now but that is an entirely unsupported configuration, I would strongly advise you to never update any of the firmware involved as this combination could cease to work at any moment and updates could easily trigger that.